# Change textColor, viewBackground & subview Background

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, reusability

I want to change view controllers background color, subviews background color, & text color on condition.

For example:

There are 2 options (A & B ViewController) on mainViewcontroller.

- If a user chooses A ViewController then it will follow its color from A to X, Y, Z ViewsControllers till I push, performSegue, or present X, Y, Z View Controllers.
- If a user chooses B ViewController then it will follow its color from B to X, Y, Z ViewsControllers till I push, performSegue or present X, Y, Z View Controllers.

Note: Those subviews could include tableview, collectionview, tableView in CollectionView Or CollectionView in tableView
Thanks in advance.

I'm using this approach

```
 if gold {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListView") as? ListView {
        vc.gold = true
        vc.mainBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        vc.labelColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.968627451, green: 0.6196078431, blue: 0.1529411765, alpha: 1)
        vc.topBarColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1)
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: "There are 2 options (A & B ViewController) on mainViewController".  Do you mean A & B views on mainViewController.  Generally if you want to push properties to a subsequent VC, you can use prepareForSegue()

Comment: @LorenRogers That's not  appropriate because if I go to A to U, V, W, X, Y, Z viewcontrollers I have to assign each n every object colors.
For example Z viewController have 2 collection views and one collectionView has 2 tableView in it,

Comment: @LorenRogers MainVC has tableView if user select first row the s/he will follow black n gold color scheme if he select second row s/he will follow white n pink scheme.

Comment: Your Z viewController has a property we'll call 'viewColor' of UIColor.  Then in the ViewController that pushes the segue, implement prepareForSegue() and get the destinationViewController as? Z viewController.  Then zViewController.viewColor = some Color.  Then inside the Z viewController your views set whatever color you want (background color I assume) collectionView.backgroundColor = self.viewColor

Comment: In that case, adopt the UITAbleViewDelegate selectCell, and depending on the cell, pass some pre-defined in IB segueIdentifier.  And again in mainVC prepareForSegue for THAT segueIdentifier pass some color

Comment: that's what I'm doing but I believe it's not a right way.
coz I have to assign each n every object color.

Comment: Something else you could do if I'm understanding you correctly, is subclass UITableViewCell and add a property called 'designatedColor'.  Then when you build your cells, you can assign that property.  Then in tableViewdidSelectRowAt, you can get that custom cell and get designated color and pass that as performSegue sender

Comment: @LorenRogers Please see my question, I post my code there and let me know if your approach is different

Comment: I have a question. Is ListView a ViewController or is it a UIListView?  If it is indeed a ViewController you may want to rename ListView to ListViewViewController.  If it is a ViewController, create a show segue in InterfaceBuilder from your source ViewController to the "ListViewViewController".  Name the segue "ListView" if you like.  Then in the source VC, do a perform(segue: "ListView"...).  Then in the source VC implementation, override prepare(for segue) as in my answer below

Comment: ListView is ViewController. Now issue is that this listview VC  is for both A & B with same objects but with different color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ThisColorSegue", sender: nil)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ThatColorSegue", sender: nil)
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SomeOtherColorSegue", sender: nil)
    }
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ThisColorSegue", let dest = segue.destination as? ZController {
        dest.color = SomeColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my question, I post my code there and let me know if your approach is different.

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, and not just post code.